# Digital picture frame simple for seniors that can pause and go forward and backward in album

Tags: displays

A senior in my life has little dexterity and comfort with technology. They love looking at photos and we got her a digital photo album from Aura Frames. This has worked well, but the frame does not allow her (or anyone) to change the speed of the slide show, or to skip ahead or go back or pause a photo.

We are looking for a digital photo frame that meets the following key criteria:

- Let's multiple people add photos from afar (family from different states)
- User-friendly way to pause, view previous, or view next photo in the album
- Optionally, it would be nice to be able to change the default pace the photos change at

Looking around I am not sure what meets these seemingly-simple criteria. I'd think these are common requests for digital photo frames, or maybe I'm missing reasons why these are not common features. The Aura frames do not have that pause/previous/next option from what I can tell. Nixplay or Loop frames might offer that, I am looking into that more now, but I wanted to ask if anyone here can recommend a device that meets this criteria.

Comment: "Senior" or "Accessibility" seem like worthwhile tags for a hardware recommendations site

Answer (score 0):

My parents use the [Skylight](https://www.skylightframe.com/). You can setup an email address for everyone to send photos to and they will show up in the reel automatically. It's very user friendly: swipe left or right and zoom with touchscreen. There is no monthly fee unless you want to sign up for their cloud backup plan.

The SD card slot is for "future functionality" that may never come, but the 8GB onboard has been more than enough so far.